# Parse nested JSON Data in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I got the following JSON Data

```
{'messages': [{'_id': '9nZFEADadMtFwEpbR', 'rid': 'GENERAL', 'msg': 'TEST ?', 'ts': '2021-02-16T12:28:47.634Z', 'u': {'_id': 'GudgiP3Am5xgThidg', 'username': 'admin'}, 'mentions': [], 'channels': [], '_updatedAt': '2021-02-16T12:28:47.655Z'}], 'success': True}
```

I want only specific values from this data, e.g. Message ID ('_id')

I tried:

```
def rocket_read():
    history = rocket.channels_history('GENERAL', count=1).json()
    x = json.dumps(history)
    # print(x)
    jsonDict = json.loads(x)
    print(jsonDict['_id'])
```

Unfortunately I still get the complete dict as output.

Any Ideas?

Comment: `jsonDict['messages'][0]['_id']`

Comment: Why are you converting to JSON and back again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first access the first key of overall dict which is messages, then the list and then keys in nested dict

jsonDict['messages'][0]['_id']